# R terra remove raster cells touching spatvector lines

Tags: r, geospatial, masking, terra

I'm trying to calculate shapes of touching raster cells within areas using terra. I haven't been able to reproduce my problem using sample data, so I hope someone might still be able to help without that (I tried, but somehow couldn't replicate the issue). Here goes:
I have a raster layer of 200mX200m cells of the US. I want to get characteristics of the largest patch of cells within each State. My current issue is that some cells/patches seem to be popping up in multiple states after later identifying patches and turning them into a SpatVector. I am now trying to figure out if the issue arises early on, when cropping and masking OR whether it is an issue that comes when turning the patches into a SpatVector (though I think it's the former and my masking is not working properly).

If anybody could help me figure out how to crop out/mask the cells that are touching a State border that would be highly appreciated!!!

Here's my current stylized approach (again, I really tried to get an example going, sorry!):

```
library(terra)

### get raster layer 
layr <- rast(file1)

### get shapefile of three bordering regions to crop
state_shp <- st_read(file2)
state2   <- vect(state_shp$geometry)

### crop & keep only what's inside state polygons 
    ## HERE NEED TO DROP ALL CELLS THAT ARE TOUCHING STATE BORDERS
layr_cropped <- crop(layr,state2   , mask=T, snap = "in")
   ##also tried: mask(layr,state2   , touches = T)


### turn into patches & then spatvector
layr_patched <- patches(layr_cropped, 8)
testvector <- terra::as.polygons(layr_patched, trunc=T, dissolve = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this problem, and neither can you, so perhaps it is something different that what you think. Your negative buffer is rather ad-hoc and would not guarantee the result you are after.

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))

x1 <- crop(r, v[1], mask=T)
x2 <- crop(r, v[2], mask=T)

x <- merge(x1, x2)
r1 <- !(extend(x1, x) |> is.na())
r2 <- !(extend(x2, x) |> is.na())

# no overlap     
plot(r1 + r2)
```

Instead of a negative buffer, you could remove the cells that are touched by the polygon vertices like this

```
m1 <- mask(x1, as.lines(v[1]), inverse=T)
```

But that would seem an odd thing to do, as these cells would now be ignored for all states.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution. You can simply add a negative buffer to the state2 file and then crop as before:

```
state2   <- vect(state_shp$geometry)
state2_buff <- buffer(state2   , width = -201)

### crop & keep only what's inside state polygons 
    ## HERE NEED TO DROP ALL CELLS THAT ARE TOUCHING STATE BORDERS
layr_cropped <- crop(layr,state2_buff , mask=T, snap = "in")
```